# Importing Modules from Cython into Python Program

Tags: python, python-import, importerror

I've spent the last hour looking at possible solutions, but none of the previous answers seems to have helped. I have two files, comp.pyx (which upon compilation becomes comp.c) and comp_exec.py.

Now comp.pyx looks something like this:

```
cdef extern from "math.h":
double sin(double x)
double cos(double x)
double sqrt(double x)
double atan(double x)
double exp(double x)
double log(double x)
double fabs(double x)

import array
import random
cimport numpy as np
import numpy as np
cimport cython

# Some other code

cdef void fm(double a, double b, double c, double d, int e, int f, int g, int h, double i, double j, double k, str l):
    #some code

def fm1 (a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l):
    fm(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l)
```

Meanwhile, comp_exec.py looks something like this (variable definitions are not the problem here):

```
import multiprocessing
import scipy
import math
import sys
import numpy as np
import comp

def doThis(x, g, h, l, tm, tn, ij, ji, sig):
    cpu = multiprocessing.cpu_count()
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=cpu)
    print "Running on", cpu, "cores."
    results = []
    for n in range(0,Nmax):
        for t in range(0,tmax):
            th = math.acos(1-t*dt)
            for p in range(0,Np):
                phi = p*dp
                filename = get_filename(n,t,p)
                temp = (x,l+k*n,a[1],a[2],a[3],a[4],a[5],a[6],th,ph,s,f)
                pool.apply_async(comp.fm1,args=temp,callback=logResult)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()

#Some code to fill array args[] with parameters from file

doThis(args[0], args[1], (etc) ..., args[8])
```

When running comp_exec.py, it tells me that 'module' object has no attribute 'fm1'. I don't believe there is any circular inheritance, and I have wrapped the fm function in the fm1 function that should be visible to comp_exec.py. What could be the problem here?

EDIT: Here is what setup.py looks like. I run the command

```
python setup.py build_ext --inplace
```

in the command prompt to compile the Cython file.

setup.py:

```
from distutils.core import setup, Extension
from Cython.Distutils import build_ext
from Cython.Build import cythonize

setup(
    ext_modules = cythonize("comp.pyx")
)
```

Comment: Can you show your setup.py? How do you compile the extension module?

Comment: @cel I made the edit to include setup.py

Answer (score 0):

I can't explain my answer, but the program began working after changing two things: 1) removing the number from the function name (i.e. changing the name "fm1" to "function") and 2) Adding a return value, for example

```
return 1
```

If anyone can explain this, that would be helpful.